# Microsoft OpenApi and Enum names x-enum-varnames c# in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, openapi

Previously I was using Swashbuckle with the Azure functions to generate swagger documentation.  With swashbuckle there was an easy way of returning the enum names with the below filter.  Now .Net 8 does not support Swashbuckle I'm struggling to work out how to achieve the same result using their Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.  Does anyone have a solution to this?  The reason for this is we were using the swagger to generate TS classes and enums so require all the names.

````cs
 public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
 {
     public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
     {
         if (context.Type.IsEnum)
         {
             var array = new OpenApiArray();
             array.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(context.Type).Select(n => new OpenApiString(n)));
             // NSwag
             schema.Extensions.Add("x-enumNames", array);
             // Openapi-generator
             schema.Extensions.Add("x-enum-varnames", array);
         }
     }
 }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use of  `ISchemaFilter` is not yet supported. I came across of this [feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/400) which is created to track down the implantation of `ISchemaFilter` in isolated function. You can refer to this request, to get the latest update.
So far only `IDocumentFilter` has been implemented as per this [feature](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/376#issuecomment-1076467991).

[image]

If you would like to use OpenAPI as Data Annotations in .Net8 isolated function then you can use the below given code.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace FunctionApp55
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
        [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
        [OpenApiParameter(name: "email", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The email address of the lead you wish to retrieve")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}
```

**program.cs**-

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**.csproj**-

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="2.0.0-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0-preview3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I am getting the output as below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to setup OpenAPI OK, just my TS generate code requires all the properties of the Enum which I could get from Swashbuckle with a simple mod.  Looking at the articles I think I can see another way I may be able to achieve this though, which I will explore.   

Essentially in my swagger I need the name of the enum, e.g. "eMyThingType".  The name of each value (Thing1, Thing2) as well as the value of each value. (1,2).